# How to fix attribute error in a class for python

Tags: python, class, attributes, self

I can't figure out how to fix this attribute error that occurs whenever I attempt to make a class without using global variables.  The error says

> AttributeError: 'Animal' object has no attribute 'habitat'.

The error occurs on line 6:

```
class Animal:
    def _init_(self):
        self.habitat = 'Jungle'
        self.diet = 'carnivore'
    def speak(self):
        print(f"I live in the {self.habitat} and eat {self.diet}")
animal_1 = Animal()
animal_1.speak()
```

Comment: Double underscore for `__init__`

Comment: Perhaps closing this question as a typo isn't the best option. It might be a simple fix but others might run into the same problem in the future and it's not exactly obvious

Comment: As an aside, having your `.speak()` method print instead of returning a string is probably not the best design choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple typo. Its `__init__` not `_init_`.
So it should be:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.habitat = 'Jungle'
        self.diet = 'carnivore'
    def speak(self):
        print(f"I live in the {self.habitat} and eat {self.diet}")
animal_1 = Animal()
animal_1.speak()
```